# how i can capture a json value if have a lot of the same value

Tags: php

i get this json response

```
    [{"app_id":"com.mojang.minecraftpe","description":"Millions of crafters have smashed billions of blocks! Now you can join the fun!","developer":"Mojang","developer_id":"4772240228547998649",
"free":false,"full_price":null,"icon":".....","price":"$7.49","score":null,"title":"Minecraft","url":"/store/apps/details?id=com.mojang.minecraftpe"},{"app_id":"com.mojang.minecraftedu","description":"Game-based learning using creativity, collaboration, and problem-solving.","developer":"Mojang",
"developer_id":"4772240228547998649","free":true,"full_price":"0","icon":"......","price":"0","score":null,"title":"Minecraft: Education Edition","url":"/store/apps/details?id=com.mojang.minecraftedu"},{"app_id":"com.appblockgames.freecraftexploration","description":"MCPE Master Game Minecraft: Mods, Maps, Servers, Skins, Addons, Textures.","developer":"Master for Minecraft","developer_id":"5713672414955811747"
,"free":true,"full_price":"0","icon":"......","price":"0","score":null,"title":"MOD-MASTER for Minecraft PE","url":"/store/apps/details?id=com.appblockgames.freecraftexploration"}
```

i want capture the first result of app_id, how i can?

Answer (score 0):

```php
$json = '<your_json_response_here>';
$array = json_decode($json, true);
$app_id = $array[0]['app_id'];
```